# How to grab all articles with comments in mongodb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

How do I grab all articles with comments? I have:

```
class Article
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_many :comments
end

class Comment
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :article
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment. This seems to work:

```
Article.where(:comments => {"$exists" => true})
```

Am I using the `$exists` directive correctly for this context?

Comment: Yes, this is correct usage of `$exists` (assuming that article without comments will not have this field at all, as opposed to having an empty array).

Answer (score 0):

Articles where comments exist (thus, not nil)

```
Article.where(:comments.ne => nil)
```